# Custom principle extractor from OAuth2 resource server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement a custom principle extractor for my web application. I have a different application for the authentication and from that, I'm validating the token that im passing. For the token validation im using `/oauth/check_token` path mapping. From internally this API is giving the below response once the token is valid.

```
{
"user_id": 13,
"user_name": "test@gmail.com",
"scope": [
    "read",
    "write"
],
"active": true,
"exp": 1649874072,
"authorities": [
    "ROLE_ADMIN",
    "ROLE_USER",
],
"client_id": "test"}
```

I have customized this request and added the user_id key value from the authentication app. I want to get this user-id value from the `@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal`. from this principle object I'm only getting logged user username. I want to use the custom principle to extract this user id from the check_token API. Currently, I'm trying to implement a principle extractor from this [refernce](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-principal-authorities-extractor) but I'm unable to extract the user id from the check_token API. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll need to implement your own `AuthenticationProvider` 's `authenticate` method, and register this provider.

```
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
  // Get user details from authentication
  MyCustomAuthentication customAuthentication = new MyCustomAuthentication();
  customAuthentication.setPrincipal(yourPrincipal);
  return customAuthentication;
}
```

Then you can use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` at Controller methods

Comment: Hi @Vinh my authentication only has the username. it doesn't contain the user-id. How do I get the user details from the authentication?

Comment: @Adek are you getting your user-id using `@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal` ?  You may need to specify a class that is a custom principal `class MyPrincipal { String userId; }`. Then change to `@AuthenticationPrincipal MyPrincipal principal`. Also make sure your authentication provider process also `setPrincipal(MyPrincipal)`